How can I fix library error in Android Studio?
I wanted to add the github library to gradle in Android Studio, but it gave the following error:
Failed to resolve: com.github.warkiz.widget:indicatorseekbar:2.1.2

I needed to add the following repositories, I added them but it still gave the same error.
allprojects { 

repositories { ... 

maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } 

} 

}

My Gradle(The libraries I marked with a yellow pen are the ones that give the same error.):




-1 because code only posted as screenshot. Screenshots are not indexed by search engines and in the end totally unnecessary.

If you want to use a dependency from GitHub, you need to add:
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } 

to your repositories, for example:
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } // this line
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

However, keep in mind that your provided library may not be still available due to JCenter's discontinuation in February 2021. If the library is not available through JitPack, you might consider adding:
maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/jcenter' }

to access old JCenter repositories as an alternative repository (I tried with your provided library com.github.warkiz.widget:indicatorseekbar:2.1.2, it worked).
Warning: You should only do this if you really need the library, as it may pose security risks. Always prioritize trusted sources to ensure the safety of your project.

Glad to hear it helped ^^

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78417745/java-lang-nullpointerexception-cannot-invoke-string-length-because-parame/78419329  (This time he gave a solution for the error in the link. All the solutions in the link barely work. Do you have a solution for the error in the link?)

Warning: Just adding other repositories maintained by unknown persons imposes serious security risk. This can open up your app and even your whole system to malware.

In your app level build gradle add corresponding library
implementation 'com.github.warkiz.widget:indicatorseekbar:2.1.2'


I installed the latest version but still the same

post your app level gradle file

I have shared the images of my app level gradle file

line number 41 why its commented?

Lines 41,43 and 46 give the same error, what is the solution?
